# JavaScript - adding style to the text of console log

Tags: javascript, css, console.log

Recently I logged into my FB account on Chrome Browser. When I opened the developer tools, I saw something like this:

[image]

Now I know that it is possible to add anything to console using the javascript `console.log` function. But my question is -- how did they add style to the text? E.g. "Stop!" is written in red tahoma font with black border and larger size. How did they do it?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Addy Osmani has a good explanation:

https://plus.google.com/+AddyOsmani/posts/TanDFKEN9Kn ([archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20140807151412/https://plus.google.com/%2BAddyOsmani/posts/TanDFKEN9Kn))

> **Styled console logging in the Chrome DevTools (Canary)**
>
> Thanks to Mr. +Mike West, you can now add style to your console log
>   via %c, just like you can in Firebug. e.g
>
> ```
> console.log("%cBlue!", "color: blue;");
> ```
>
> Blocks such as `console.log('%cBlue! %cRed!', 'color: blue;', 'color: red;');` are also now supported :)
>
> Whilst most people will probably use this for practical purposes, it's
>   also possible to have a little fun with it :) (see below)
>
> Not to be outdone, here's what +Mike West  came up with a few days ago
>   [image]
>
> ;)
>
> Relevant change: http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/130941

---

Basically, you can use the `%c` paramater to pass in CSS styling. For an example, try the following in your chrome console:

```js
console.log("%cBlue! %cGreen", "color: blue; font-size:15px;", "color: green; font-size:12px;");
```

Comment: This is correct but generally it's preferred that you at least paraphrase the link, just in case the link ever goes down.

Comment: @MikeC Added in an edit :)

Comment: @khalid13 Got it. One more thing I learnt from this post. This is how Chrome shows a warning to the web developers for using `dppx` instead of `dpi` in the media queries. [link] (http://imgur.com/5UGcVOw)

Comment: @MikeC sorry, I am new in StackOverflow. What is "paraphrasing" a link? I'm asking so that I can keep it in mind while answering to someone else.

Comment: @RuchirGupta Paraphrasing just means to sum up the information. Basically, you take the important information from the link and write it in the answer.

Comment: Ty! Just to add, line breaks `(\n)` work as well, any other secrets? :)

Comment: is there a way to set the default style for console messages

Comment: This is not supported in all browsers. Chrome and FF are OK. IE11 is not. Don't know about others. Is there a way to sniff for this feature?

Comment: This only seems to work in the first parameter, i.e `console.log('%cyellow', 'background: yellow')` works, but not `console.log(123, '%cyellow', 'background: yellow')`. Is there a trick to do that?

Comment: A bit late, but `%_` for any `_` is a formatting placeholder, these only work in the first position. For the above case, `console.log('%d %cyellow', 123, 'background: yellow')` works. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Outputting_text_to_the_console) has more info.

Comment: Link is now broken because Google+ has closed.

Comment: @Anwar Thanks. I've added an archive.org link now, and copied it main text into a blockquote here.